# Proof of : " Union of all R-equivalence classes on A is included in A" based on " R is a subset of A² ". ( Q° on Ayres, Problems Modern Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying Ayres *Theory and Problems of Modern Algebra*.

In Chapter 2, Solved Problem 6, the question is asked to prove that " An equivalence relation R on a set S effects a partition of S."

Ayers notes T(a) , T(b), T(c), etc.  the equivalence classes of ( respectively) the elements a, b, c , etc belonging to the set S.

Aiming at proving first that the union of all equivalent classes is equal to S (which is the first condition for the set of equivalence classes to be a partition of S), Ayres only says : " Since p belongs to [p] , it is clear that S is the union of all the distinct subsets T(a), T(b), T(c)."

My question is: knowing that to prove a set equality, a reciprocal inclusion has to be shown, does the argument given by Ayres prove inclusion in **both directions**?

May I develop Ayre's argument in the following way?

(1) **Proving that S is included in the union of the family of equivalence classes.**

Suppose p belongs to A. Since pRp ( given reflexivity) , p belongs to the R-equivalence class [p]. But the union of the set of R-equivalence classes on A is

```
       { x | x belongs to at least one R-equivalence class on A}.
```

So, knowing that [p] is an R-equivalence class on A and that p belongs to [p], it follows that **p belongs to at least one R-equivalence class on A**, and, therefore, to the union of the set of R-equivalence classes on A.

(2) **Proving that the union of R-equivalence classes on A is included in A.**

Suppose that x belongs to the union of R-equivalence classes.

It means that x belongs to at least one equivalence class ( by the definition of " union") , say the class [a].

So there exists an element *a* belonging to A such that : *xRa*, that is such that 
**(x,a) belongs to R.**

But R ( being a relation on A) is a subset of A².

So **(x,a) belongs to A²**.

But A² is the set of all pairs such that both their first and second element belong to A.

So the first element of (x,a) belongs to A.

So x belongs to A.

Since x was arbitrary, we can conclude that for all x, if x belongs to the union of the set of R-equivalence classes on A, then x belongs to A; in other words, that the union of the set of R-equiv classes is included in A.

Comment: Well, $T(a) \subseteq S$ for all $a \in S$. In other words, $S \subseteq \bigcup_{a \in S} T(a) \subseteq S$.

Comment: Technically, you are correct; however, in many circumstances, including this one, one of the inclusions is “trivial”, “immediate”, etc. Here, since each of the sets $T(x)$ is a subset of $S$ by construction, their union is a subset of $S$; so the only non-trivial part to check is that $S$ is contained in the union.